# How many words in "zuzulegen" or "zuzuschreiben"?

Tags: verb, prefix, vocabulary, infinitive, inflection

I am a native speaker born in Germany and still living here, but I have trouble with words as described in the topic. Do the words

> zuzulegen

and

> zuzuschreiben

consists of 1, 2 or 3 words? Let me know and maybe the rules I need to know.

From Google you get any possible answer since there are some more people who don't know how to use it I guess ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your examples are usages of the verb prefix *"zu-"* which can be found quite often for the following usages to indicate:

> - **a direction:** *zubewegen, zufließen, zutreten, zulächeln, ...*
> - **an endpoint of movements:** *zuziehen, zuwandern, ...*
> - **an addition (short for *dazu*):** *zufügen, zutun, zusetzen, ...*
> - **the a closing process:** *zubinden, zukleben, zuschließen, ...*
> - **the putting into a shape:** *zureiten, zuschneiden, zustutzen, ...*

Both of your examples hence are prefixed verbs *"zu-legen"*, and *"zu-schreiben"* in the case when the prefix *"zu-"* is a (colloquial!) short of *"dazu"*.

When building the [infinitive with *"zu"*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Infinitiv.html?lang=en) from these verbs we always have to put this between prefix and verb resulting in *"zu**zu**legen"*, or *"zu**zu**schreiben"*.

Only if we count the prefix, the infinitive attribute, and the verb as separate *"word"* (or morpheme) each we can count to three. However from a grammatical point of view it is only one compound verb in its infinitve form we have here.

Comment: danke dir! Das störte mich schon so lange :), also es nicht zu wissen.

Answer (score 0):

***zu**'zu'**legen*** is a compound of the word ***zulegen*** and the infinitive form '*zu*'.

The word ***zulegen*** again is a compound of ***legen*** and ***zu***, the short form of ***dazu*** or ***hinzu***.

So the original word consists of three parts that could each stand for themselves in a regular sentence and thus count as individual words:

> Um dies '*zu*' verdeutlichen, ***füge*** ich ein Beispiel ***hinzu***.

Answer (score -1):

Gar nicht so einfach zu beantworten, wenn man mal darüber nachdenkt. :) Also mal Schritt für Schritt:

- »legen« ist ein Wort, genauer: ein Verb
- »zu« ist ein Wort, genauer: eine Präposition
- »zulegen« ist ein Verb, zusammengesetzt aus zwei Wörtern
- »zu« wird (zufällig) auch für den Infinitiv gebraucht
- Beispiel: »… den Arm heben, um die Hand auf den Tisch zu legen …« => zwei Wörter (oder nur eines, wenn man sagt: das infinitivische »zu« zählt logisch nicht)
- Beispiel: »… den Preis heben, um im nächsten Quartal zuzulegen …« => ein Wort im anderen => also auch zwei Wörter (oder nur eines, wie oben); oder doch zwei Wörter, wenn man sagt: »zulegen« besteht aus zwei Wörtern wie »turn on« im Englischen.

Letztlich ist es egal, wie viele Wörter es sind oder wie viele man sich denkt. Die klare Trennung gibt es ja nur in der Schrift. In der (gesprochenen) Sprache sind die Grenzen nicht so klar, da man sie eben hört und nicht sieht.

Sieh es mal so:

Schrift gliedert Sprache in Buchstabenwürmer (sogenannte Wörter). Was ist ein Wort? Etwas, das durch Leerraum oder Satzzeichen abgegrenzt ist. Ist ja offensichtlich, im Buch, auf dem Bildschirm, überall … Man sieht ein Wort als *räumliche* Einheit.

Aber *logisch* gesehen passt diese räumliche Bestimmung eben nicht immer. Logisch haben wir in deinem Beispiel das Wort »zulegen«. Dies arme Wort muss nun in eine Infinitivkonstruktion. Es kommt ein »zu« dazu. Räumlich kommt das »zu« *hinein* (*in* das Verb), aber logisch *hinzu* (*zum* Verb).

Die Antwort auf deine Frage ist also, dass wir nicht genau bestimmt haben, was eigentlich ein Wort ist, und deswegen je nach Bestimmung sagen können: Es sind ein, zwei oder drei Wörter! Alles ist irgendwo richtig. :)